# Android studio renders same layout differently

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, rendering

I'm trying to use some portions of my previous project in my new project but I have encountered with a strange problem. My new project renders the same layout differently from the previous project. Here is the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/id1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

And here are the two different results:

[image: Layout 1]

[image]

Layouts are 100% same but in the first one, ImageView holds a larger space than the image. In the second one, ImageView wraps the image, no extra space around the image. I want to use second one but what am I missing?

Target sdk, min sdk etc. are all the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get the layout from second pic, your `FrameLayout` should have width & height set to `match_parent`. The orientation `android:orientation="vertical"` needs to go. It does not apply to `FrameLayout`. And `android:layout_gravity="center"` should be applied to the `ImageView`, not the `FrameLayout`. As for why this is happening, no idea. I'll have to look at your project(s).

Comment: @Vikram doesn't work either

Comment: Maybe not sure but in first case you might be setting the image as a background and in second case as an image src.

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia but I'm using the same .xml file

Comment: In my experience, the layout preview in Studio has lots of bugs. Have you tried running both apps on the same device to see what the layouts look like? More likely than not, they will both look the same.

Comment: Same emulator size? Maybe one project uses images in `drawable-*` rather than `drawable` with a different size?

Comment: @JarettMillard I have also tried in samsung galaxy s3

Answer (score 1):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:paddingRight="50dp"
             android:paddingLeft="50dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

You may want to try this code above. Adjust the paddings as you want!

Comment: I think this is solution. Since you define width as wrap_content, you cant guarantee if it is centered or fills screen. Putting right, left padding is trick. Also i would change FrameLayout's width, height to matchParent

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/id1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
</FrameLayout>
```